# How to show React Native Push Notification when app is closed

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-push-notification

I am using React Native Push Notification (local notification)[https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification].

The logic to show notification is like below.

I used "onSnapshot" function in react-native to check the firestore data is changed or not.

If changed, I showed local notification in the app.

```
...
const ref = firestore().collection('players');
return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        ....
        // called push notification
        PushNotification.localNotification({
            channelId,
            title,
            message,
            bigText,
        });
    });
});
...
```

When the app is in the foreground or background, it works well. (Android and iOS)

What I want is to show this push notification when the app is closed.

I saw some blogs but until now, I couldn't find the solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When the app is closed, your database listener will no longer be listening at all. Android and iOS completely shut down app processes that are not visible to the user.  This saves battery and data for the end user.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, Thanks for your reply. I just tested push notification, so it works well when the app is closed. Problem is firestore. Do you have any idea to know firestore status when the app is closed?

Comment: As I said, your listener will no longer be listening when the app is closed.

Comment: So I am going to detect the firestore status when the app is actived or closed and if data is changed, then I am going to show notification. That's my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase cloud messaging which works even your app closed. But if someone change data so it's not possible as app terminate all the activity, after closing. So, you need to use Headless js to call your task in background. but for efficiency of app you can consider react-native-backgound-fetch. Then call your task in background.

Here's how you can do it:

step 1- install https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-fetch
step 2- create headless js
step 3 - initialize your task into it ( as shown in document in above package)

Comment: Hi @Alesha. Sorry for late response. I solved my issue. I can't connect to the database when the app is terminated so I used fcm. Thanks.